# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to create a plugin in wxpython and running into below error,can any one help understand why I am running into this error and how to fix this?

```
import wx
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC 


class TestFrame(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        APPNAME = 'plugin'
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, size=wx.Size(600,700), title=APPNAME, style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self.frame, -1)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(180)
        panel1 = wx.Panel(splitter, size=wx.Size(-1, 300))
        commands_panel = wx.Panel(panel1, -1)
        package_panel = wx.Panel(commands_panel, -1)
        self.view_listctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(package_panel, id=-1,columns=2,selectionType=1)
        package_vbox.Add(self.view_listctrl, 2, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        #view_listctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(package_panel, id=-1)
        itemCount = int('2')
        for x in range(0,itemCount):
            view_listctrl.SetItemKind(x, 2 , 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TestFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listctr.py", line 26, in <module>
    frame = TestFrame()
  File "listctr.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.view_listctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(package_panel, id=-1,columns=2,selectionType=1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [the documentation for the class's `__init__`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.html#wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl.UltimateListCtrl.__init__), you can see that it has no [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) `columns`, and yet you're trying to pass one:

```
self.view_listctrl = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(package_panel, id=-1,columns=2,selectionType=1)
```

It's basically exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Ami - I am importing from `from UIElements import OutputConsole` ,where can I install UIElements from?

Comment: @kemosabee I don't see that in the code in your question. Is this a new question? If so, could you please open a new one? It's the way things are done on SO. If you drop here a link, I'll be happy to look at it.

Comment: Ami - okay I will raise a new one

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Not only for the question, but for any other questions that you would ask in future.